# How do you list you stack exchange apps

Tags: support, editing

I wanted to know how you're supposed to get a list of apps you've registered on the stack exchange api.

I finally managed to find this url: https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth

My question is this: How are supposed to find this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "How are supposed to find this page?"

There is a link to the page for registering an application on Stack Apps directly on the [site home page](https://stackapps.com/):

[image]

Comment: No idea why I couldn't see that before.

Comment: Though the actual link is the one below that you've highlighted.